# Problem pertaining to DepthGenerator

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying to run the Kinect sensor for the first time but having an error as follows after invoking a command "roslaunch openni_camera openni_kinect.launch":

"[ERROR] [1297966723.977913245]: [OpenNIDriver] Failed to create DepthGenerator: Can't create any node of the requested type!
Please see http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni/Troubleshooting for more info.
[openni_camera-1] process has died [pid 3429, exit code -11].
log files: /home/shah/.ros/log/1f8c4fae-3ac1-11e0-881b-d7b53128cee2/openni_camera-1*.log"

I am aware that there is a post regarding this one and its corresponding solution as in "https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=49868&action=ListThreads&mailman_id=39", however after following the steps I'm still trapped there.

Could somebody guide me on this problem..BTW i'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and on 64-bit machine.

Thanks in advance.

-alfa-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9105/problem-pertaining-to-depthgenerator/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-02-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-17**:
alfa_80, you can edit your question to add this in.  And please mark the answer that you said fixed the problem below as accepted.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-17**:
[ERROR] [1297966723.977913245]: [OpenNIDriver] Failed to create DepthGenerator: Can't create any node of the requested type!
Please see http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni/Troubleshooting for more info.
[openni_camera-1] process has died [pid 3429, exit code -11].
log files: /home/shah/.ros/log/1f8c4fae-3ac1-11e0-881b-d7b53128cee2/openni_camera-1*.log

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-17**:
Very sorry I didn't realize it about putting the error, just forgotten..it might be useful for the others..Hence, this is the error: [ERROR] [1297966723.977913245]: [OpenNIDriver] Failed to create DepthGenerator: Can't create any node of the requested type!
Please see http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni/Troubleshooting for more info.
[openni_camera-1] process has died [pid 3429, exit code -11].
log files: /home/shah/.ros/log/1f8c4fae-3ac1-11e0-881b-d7b53128cee2/openni_camera-1*.log

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-17**:
Could you add the exact error about the DepthGenerator to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One possible problem is that you do not have the 12V power plugged in.  The device will give this error if the 12V power source is not enabled.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-02-17**:
please check the check circle next to the answer to mark it as answered

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-17**:
Definitely, the power source is not connected :-( Thanks a lot What is probable problem with this warning when i run rviz: "[ WARN] [1297970327.355692647]: Message from [/openni_camera] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [openni_rgb_optical_frame]. Resolved locally to [/openni_rgb_optical_frame].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once." How to resolve it locally? I didn't get it..

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-17**:
Definitely, the power source is not connected :-( Thanks a lot